# Swiftmailer with gmail

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

So I am trying to use swiftmailer to send emails using a gmail account.  I know there are questions that address this issue, but none of the proposed solutions have helped me. My problem is that when I run my code I get "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted." I know that my password and username are correct, and the Google two-step verification is not enabled. Here is my code:

require_once 'vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift.php';
    Swift::registerAutoload();

```
require_once 'vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php';
require_once 'vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/swift_init.php';

$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 587, 'tls')
    ->setUsername ('myemail@gmail.com')
    ->setPassword ('mypassword');

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);    

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Weekly Hours')
    ->setFrom (array('myemail@gmail.com' => 'My Name'))
    ->setTo (array('recipient@hotmail.com' => 'Recipient'))
    ->setSubject ('Weekly Hours')
    ->setBody ($data, 'text/html');

$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

Note that I have also tried port 465 with 'lss' encryption. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean "ssl" encryption right?

Comment: Looks like there is an uncaught exception. Can you tell the script and line in which the error is occurring?

Comment: Can you [check to see if this is enabled on your Gmail account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send email using the GMail SMTP server from a PHP page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-the-gmail-smtp-server-from-a-php-page)

Answer (score -1):

The problem could be related to the fact that google can use a range of IPs.

I solved the problem in my case with something like this:

```
 #get the host dynamically
 $smtp_host_ip = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');

 #set the transport
 $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance($smtp_host_ip,465,'ssl')->setUsername('myemail@gmail.com')->setPassword('mypassword');
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: If it received a response and error code, it obviously was able to connect to the server. (Besides, I tried this and it didn't work.)